# Comparison based on derived operator in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have a scenario where the comparison operation to be performed is in words, i.e `Greater than, Less than` etc. I have tom derive the operator i.e `Greater than = >, less than = <,` etc. I have to then use the operator in a data frame column and write the comparison result in another `dataframe` column

I used a dictionary, to define the conversion list and used that operator in the dataframe comparison as follows

```
condition={"LESSER THAN":"<","GREATER THAN":">"}
check_cond=condition["GREATER THAN"] #value from db table
df=pd.DataFrame(df[df['col_to_compare'].notnull() & check_cond(df['col_to_compare'],1)])
```

I get an error 'str' object is not callable, how do i fix it?

Comment: Please post sample input data with expected output.

Comment: `"<"` and `">"` are *strings*. So `check_condition` is a string. You can't call a string.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method and calculate your result. Just modify below code with respect to your string comparison.

```
import pandas as pd

def compareValue(c,v):
  if c > v:
    return 'Greater than '+ str(v)
  #Write other comparisons here
  return 'Less than '+ str(v)

data = pd.DataFrame([{'c1':1},{'c1':2},{'c1':3},{'c1':4}]) #Base data from csv/list/dictonary...
data['comparison'] = data.apply(lambda r: compareValue(r['c1'],2), axis=1)
print(data)
```

[image: c1 is my data, comparison is my result]